# How do I "get" an element from the HTML that is a "data-index" on Selenium IDE webdriver (Chrome)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

[image: Selenium][image: HTML]I want to do a click on somethink in a website, but the problm is that I get an error: `Element <td style="">...</td> is not clickable at point (366, 304). Other element would receive the click: <div class="fixed-table-loading"` but where I want to click, does not have a class, it only have's a `data-index` what can I use to "click" on it ?

Comment: Can you use xpath ? if yes then can you share HTML here

Comment: I actually dont know if its possible to use xpath on selenium IDE but I'll put a screenshot of the selenium and the HTML here

Comment: I can help in Selenium webdriver but not certainly in IDE. I never installed Selenium IDE

Comment: Sorry about the black rectangles but its kind of a "personal information"

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css selector for finding that element,

```
tr[data-index='0']
```

However the error "`Element <td style="">...</td> is not clickable at point (366, 304). Other element would receive the click: <div class="fixed-table-loading"`" you are getting is not means that you doing false operation, it means that where selenium find your desired element to click, there is already a different element on that position and it will be getting that click.

So, first you need to focus on your element or if it is a member of a dropdown or opening list you need to first open that dropdown and then you should have click your element.